# Define Number of processor in MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Is there any command in MPI like omp_set_num_threads in OpenMP to define number of processor?? I usually define number of processor in terminal with mpirun -np (numberofprocess) but i want to define it in body algoritms like OpenMP. is there a solution in MPI? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, the answer is no.

That being said, you can use `MPI_Comm_spawn()` in order to manually spawn new MPI tasks. In the context of MPI, spawn basically `fork`&`exec` new processes, which means these processes will start in the `main` function.
This is very different from a multithreaded app (such as OpenMP) in which you can create a new thread and have it start directly where you need.
Also, you can use `MPI_Comm_disconnect()` to "let the spawned tasks go" (from a pragmatic point of view, these tasks are free to `exit()`, and this is likely what they should do).

At first glance, a more MPI'ish approach would be to start all your tasks with `mpirun`, and then `MPI_Comm_split()` and do the computation in a smaller (sub)communicator and have other tasks wait in a `MPI_Barrier()`.
(note these tasks will likely use CPU, but they are free to do some other work instead of sitting in a barrier).